# Call UiViewController From Callback

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alamofire

I work with swift , I have simple situation. I want to call new UiViewController form callback function, my code is here

```
    var orderActions=OrderServices();
    orderActions.addOrder(self.order, controller: self,orderServiceCallback:{
        (data:AnyObject?,err:String?) in

        if( err == nil ){
            var booking=self.getControllerByStoryBoardIdentifier(BookingViewController.getIdentifier()) as! BookingViewController;
    self.presentViewController(booking, animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
    });
```

this code not calling `BookingViewController`, but it is working without `addOrder` function

Error Message is here :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <BookingViewController: 0x7f94ec810f40> on <MainViewController: 0x7f94e37385e0> which is already presenting (null)
```

p.s I used Alamofire library

Comment: Are you sure the code can went into the if block?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, Yes I am sure

Comment: It seems that inside the function `addOrder` you create a new local object `booking` and try to show it with `self.presentViewController(booking...)`,  then exits the function and the object is removed becouse it was only local object for your function `addOrder`. You have to create ViewController object before `addOrder` calling and inside `addOrder` only present it

Comment: by "this code not calling BookingViewController" , it means you cannot instantiate the BookingViewController or present it? Did you get some error code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate view controller like this

```
var booking = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Loginn") as! BookingViewController
self.presentViewController(booking, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I usedinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier behind getControllerByStoryBoardIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping, I have found answer , there it is.

UIKit is not thread safe. The UI should only be updated from main thread.

In my case my code must be in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

}
```